# Can OIOSAML run as SAML SP in an Azure Website?

Tags: azure, saml-2.0

We are trying to run OIOSAML as an SAML SP in an Azure Website, but we encounter problems regarding the signing certificates.  Azure websites will not allow us to install custom certificates, hence our SigningCertificate under the Federation node in the web.config file cannot be found.  Do we have to move over to a Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Web Sites team is currently working to add this feature.  Specifically adding the ability for web sites to optionally load profiles which will support more certificate loading scenarios.  The ETA for this work to be in production is within 2 weeks.

To help ensure we will be supporting your scenario, if you can provide a representative code snippet which is failing, we will validate that it works with the fix, before we go to production.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Will this feature allow us to load a self signed certificate with private key pair from a certificate store like <SigningCertificate findValue="C2DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFAF9C5" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" /> ?  
A code snipplet would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The [Kentor.AuthServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices/) SAML2 SP package can load certificates from files in App_Data and works on Azure. The Kentor implementation is not as complete as OIOSAML (yet, we're working on it) but if the functionality it offers is enough for you it can be an option.